# Twilio <Pay> Connector Options?

Tags: twilio, stripe-payments, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm using the Twilio `<Pay>` Connector with Stripe in an ongoing project, and I was hoping to find documentation anywhere that would suggest that there's an easy setting to give the customer a choice to save their payment information on file with Stripe. Does anybody know of such an option?

If I can avoid building another form system, I'd prefer to do so. I'd like to do this via the Twilio system, but I don't know how secure the system would be for gathering card information outside of the `<Pay>` Connector.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the tokenization, documented below.

[Pay Frequently Asked Questions](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023743633--Pay-Frequently-Asked-Questions)

"Pay supports "Auth and Capture" (authorization and capture of funds for a one-time charge), as well as tokenization (for subscriptions, multiple charges, or changing charge amounts)."

"When tokenizing a credit card or ACH payment, the  chargeAmount should be 0 to indicate that you are requesting tokenization of the payment. Otherwise, Twilio will attempt to execute a payment."

The Pay Connector webpage has more information on [capabilities](https://www.twilio.com/console/add-ons/XB304ed87c2c2b2b87c93fa7d31a6ac883), viewable from the Twilio Console.

[Twilio Pay](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pay)

Comment: So just to be clear on one thing, the only difference between a tokenization and an authorization is that a tokenization charges the card $0?

Comment: Yes, that is my take on it, based on the product documentation, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pay#chargeamount.